# Displaying select tag in dataTables (CodeIgniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to display the list of data from `$item_info` into a select option. It has 4 result. But I have problem displaying it.

```
foreach( $query->result_array() as $row ) {  // preparing an array for table tbody            
    $nestedData   = array();
    $nestedData[] = strtoupper($row["itemname"]);
    $nestedData[] = number_format($row["qty"], 2);


    $item_id = 123;
    $item_info = $this->get_item_information_requisition($item_id);
    $select = array();

    foreach($item_info as $item) {          
        array_push($select, $item->supplierid);
    }

    $nestedData[] = '<select><option>'.$select.'</option></select>';
```

The result of `$select` are 129,129,313,313.

What would be the proper syntax for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach( $query->result_array() as $row ) {  // preparing an array for table tbody            
$nestedData   = array();
$nestedData[] = strtoupper($row["itemname"]);
$nestedData[] = number_format($row["qty"], 2);


$item_id = 123;
$item_info = $this->get_item_information_requisition($item_id);
$select = array();

foreach($item_info as $item) {          
    $nestedData[] = '<option value="'.$item->supplierid.'">'.$item->supplierid.'</option>';
}
}
```